# selenium with python : The requested mouse movement to would be outside the bounds of the current view port

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
location = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, xpath))).location
logger.info("x:{}，y:{}".format(location['x'], location['y']))
ActionChains(self.browser).move_by_offset(location['x'], location['y']).perform()
```

I can know that the location (1013, 237), however ,it's (1638,520) when I use `move_by_offset`

Exception :

```
Message: The requested mouse movement to (1638, 520) would be outside the bounds of the current view port (left: 0, right: 1366, top: 77, bottom: 728)
```

what's wrong with my code ?
how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

To move to element, you can use following aproach.

Use `.location_once_scrolled_into_view`:

```
element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, xpath)))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Or `.execute_script`:

```
element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, xpath)))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', element)
```

Or `.move_to_element`:

```
element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, xpath)))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: Website can only be used on IE. `move_to_element` is not work